# Cannot connect to mysql from within a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

Bulding a mysql based image as follows (`Dockerfile`):

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY somescripts* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and then exec-ing into it:

```
docker run --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" -it theimagejustbuilt bash
```

but ...

```
root@73857bf5744e:/# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Same problem here, but the mysql is not running in a container, but in the host. I've tried connecting to 172.17.0.1 (the ip for the host from within the container). The permissions are set to accept connections from '%' in the DB. I thought this question was asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was accidentaly overriding the entrypoint via the following command:

```
docker run --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" -it theimagejustbuilt bash
```

the `bash` keyword at the end is not needed since it overrides the default entrypoint and connection to `mysql` service is therefore not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.** Specify "127.0.0.1" as the host instead of localhost, i.e. mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root instead of mysql. Note that if you omit the host (mysql -u root) the MySQL client will implicitly use localhost.

**Solution 2.** In /etc/mysql/my.cnf you should see this near the top of the file:

```
[client]
port          = 3306
socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Change socket to the location of your MemSQL socket file. By default, this is /var/lib/memsql/data/memsql.sock.
```